# Setting up SSL certificates for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, ssl, openssl

I tried to use [this](http://www.allanbank.com/blog/security/tls/x.509/2014/10/13/tls-x509-and-mongodb/) to set up my MongoDB deployment to use SSL, and I'm getting a certificate verification error:

```
2014-12-29T09:23:48.225+0000 [conn5] ERROR: SSL peer certificate validation failed:self signed certificate
2014-12-29T09:23:48.225+0000 [conn5] warning: could't check isSelf (salt-master.omri.myorg.com:30000) socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for
```

My configuration file's SSL section looks like this:

```
security:
  clusterAuthMode: x509
  authorization: enabled
net:
  ssl:
    mode: preferSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb_chain.crt
    allowInvalidCertificates:  false
    weakCertificateValidation: false
```

My mongodb_chain.crt is built using `cat signing-ca-1.crt root-ca.crt >> mongodb_chain.crt`.

Any ideas what could be the problem with my configuration? Anything else I should add to mongodb_chain.crt?

EDIT:

Reading [this](http://blog.edgecloud.com/post/19519955133/ssl-certificate-chain-order-matters) it comes to me that maybe it's the root certificate that's self-signed. Any way I can make it work?

Comment: Can you post what all of the certificates are that you are using (client, server, and certificate authorities) and the relations (e.g., A signs B) for each? Can you also verify that the certificate used by the MongoDB client (which I think is presenting the salt-master.omri.myorg.com certificate) is the signed version? Same thing for the server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I managed to switch jobs in the meantime. So even though I wish to know what I've done wrong, I have no access to the material... Thanks again :-)